# how to have more than one InvokeAsync in my component class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

is it possible to put more than one InvokeAsync in my components?
because my components are sometimes returned small things and if I create different files and classes for each one it's hard to manage them

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
    int maxPriority, bool isDone)
{
    string MyView = "Default";
    // If asking for all completed tasks, render with the "PVC" view.
    if (maxPriority > 3 && isDone == true)
    {
        MyView = "PVC";
    }
    var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
    return View(MyView, items);
}

public async Task<IViewComponentResult> myInvokeAsync2(
    int maxPriority, bool isDone)
{
    string MyView = "Default";
    // If asking for all completed tasks, render with the "PVC" view.
    if (maxPriority > 3 && isDone == true)
    {
        MyView = "PVC";
    }
    var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
    return View(MyView, items);
}
```

and how to call it?

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PriorityList", new { maxPriority = 4, isDone = true })
@await Component.myInvokeAsync2("PriorityList", new { maxPriority = 4, isDone = true })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a component can only have one `InvokeAsync` method:
[View components in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

However, if all of the methods you want to invoke take the same set of parameters, you you could pass in an extra parameter to specify the method to call.

```
public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
    int method, int maxPriority, bool isDone) => method switch
{
    2 => Method2(maxPriority, isDone),
    _ => Method1(maxPriority, isDone),
}

private async Task<IViewComponentResult> Method1(
    int maxPriority, bool isDone)
{
    ...
}

private async Task<IViewComponentResult> Method2(
    int maxPriority, bool isDone)
{
    ...
}
```

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PriorityList", new { method = 1, maxPriority = 4, isDone = true })
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PriorityList", new { method = 2, maxPriority = 4, isDone = true })
```